# Lag of the value, take the previous value logic

Tags: r

Here is what I try to achieve on `whatiwant` column:

```
df1 <- data.frame(value = c(99.99,99.98,99.97,99.96,99.95,99.94,
                            99.93,99.92,99.91,99.9,99.9,99.9),
                  new_value = c(NA,NA,99.98,NA,99.97,NA,
                                NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  whatiswant = c(99.99,99.96,99.98,99.95,99.97,99.94,
                                 99.93,99.92,99.91,99.9,99.9,99.9))
```

To explain it with words `whatiswant` should have the value of `new_value` and for those not having the `new_value`, it should take the next lowest value available.

I think it is kind of a lag stuff. Here is the data.frame:

```
   value new_value whatiswant
1  99.99        NA      99.99
2  99.98        NA      99.96
3  99.97     99.98      99.98
4  99.96        NA      99.95
5  99.95     99.97      99.97
6  99.94        NA      99.94
7  99.93        NA      99.93
8  99.92        NA      99.92
9  99.91        NA      99.91
10 99.90        NA      99.90
11 99.90        NA      99.90
12 99.90        NA      99.90
```

**EDIT**: Logic explained in following steps:

1. Step 1. if new_value is not NA then col3 takes the value. So the 3rd and
   5th row are sorted.
2. Step 2. 1st row col3 takes the value of col1, as col2 is NA.
3. Step 3. 2nd row col3 takes the value of col1-row4, as 2nd and 3nd
   row values for col1 is already used in Step 1.
4. Step 4. 4th row col3 takes the value of col1-row5, as all above rows
       from col1 are taken in previous steps.
5. Step 5. The rest of the rows6-12 in col3 take the same value from
   col1-rows6-12 as col2 is NA and non of the numbers col1-row6-12 are
   used in previous steps.

Comment: I can't work out how those three columns relate to each other either... you really need to put a bit more effort into your question.

Comment: @N8TRO see edit, it must be clear now. Please re-open.

Comment: @patrick Do you agree we can't fill the two last row, as 9.90 is already used in row 10 ?

Comment: @Tensibai . No you can , if all the values are already used  then the default value should be the minimum value of col1.

Comment: Ok I'll adapt in this way in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In form of a function, each step in comment, ask if it's unclear:

```
t1 <- function(df) {
  df[,'whatiswant'] <- df[,'new_value'] # step 1, use value of new_value
  sapply(1:nrow(df),function(row) { # loop on each row
    x <- df[row,] # take the row, just to use a single var instead later
    ret <- unlist(x['whatiswant']) # initial value
    if(is.na(ret)) { # If empty
      if (x['value'] %in% df$whatiswant) { # test if corresponding value is already present
        ret <- df$value[!df$value %in% df$whatiswant][1] # If yes take the first value not present
      } else {
        ret <- unlist(x['value']) # if not take this value
      }
    }
    if(is.na(ret)) ret <- min(df$value) # No value left, take the min
    df$whatiswant[row] <<- ret # update the df from outside sapply so the next presence test is ok.
  })
  return(df) # return the updated df
}
```

Output:

```
>df1[,3] <- NA # Set last column to NA
> res <- t1(df1)
> res
   value new_value whatiswant
1  99.99        NA      99.99
2  99.98        NA      99.96
3  99.97     99.98      99.98
4  99.96        NA      99.95
5  99.95     99.97      99.97
6  99.94        NA      99.94
7  99.93        NA      99.93
8  99.92        NA      99.92
9  99.91        NA      99.91
10 99.90        NA      99.90
11 99.90        NA      99.90
12 99.90        NA      99.90
```

Comment: Edit : I understand sorry , it is this line : that helps  df$whatiswant[row] <<- ret                                                                                              I've some trouble to understand the sapply because if i run linebyline i don't find the result i want. example : for the second raw i should fine 99.96 instead of 99.99 no ?                                                                                           x <- df[2,]
ret <- unlist(x['whatiswant'])
x['value'] %in% df$whatiswant
ret <- df$value[!df$value %in% df$whatiswant][1]
ret returns 99.99 instead of 99.96 .

Comment: Yes I forgot to write note about `<<-` operator which assign in local scope (function) and parent scope (sapply )